# Insert an interstitial banner in a libgdx project that produces both android ios ( robovm )

Tags: libgdx, admob, google-play-services, ads

I opened this question because I would like to do a bit of clarity on how to add an interstitial banner using AdMob in a libgdx project AndroidStudio.
I state that : I followed several tutorials ... I installed Playservice google .. but I can not understand why some classes I did not find them despite importanto everything you need .

1. So , I created my ID app to connect it to the banner via the convenient panel AdMob Google
2. i can try follow this tutorial: [AdMob Integration](http://www.norakomi.com/tutorial_admob_part2_interstitial_ads.php)
3. I am not clear how to add the class : InterstitialAd
4. In practice, I have only created the confusion..some using external projects , other strange libraries :) And ' possible to write lines of code as they should be allowing me to show or hide the banner ? nothing more complicated.

My goal is to create the banner ( both of ios ( robovm ) and on Android ) , and remove it after a timer ... but I 've come too confusion..should clarify ideas on the operation . It ' the first time you use the services ads in an app . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you intend on using a library, go to the original documentation rather than grabbing some probably out of data and potentially unreliable tutorial that you found online.

Try https://developers.google.com/admob/ instead.